# A newer version of the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin is required, please update your firebase_core pubspec dependency

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error when trying to build a Flutter project in VSCode. The same project worked before but now it stoped working.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Fltr\DevSoftware\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.2\android\build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':cloud_firestore'.
> A newer version of the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin is required, please update your firebase_core pubspec dependency.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 730ms
```

Line 28 of build.gradle is marked by **..** , its the last line here:

```
def firebaseCoreProject = findProject(':firebase_core')
if (firebaseCoreProject == null) {
    throw new GradleException('Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin, have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec?')
} else if (!firebaseCoreProject.properties['FirebaseSDKVersion']) {
    **throw new GradleException('A newer version of the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin is required, please update your firebase_core pubspec dependency.')**
}
```

this is the important part of my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  package_info_plus: ^1.0.6
  package_info_plus_web: ^1.0.4
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.2
  cloud_functions: ^3.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.1
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.7
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  get: ^4.3.8
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  google_place: ^0.4.3
  in_app_review: ^2.0.3
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^19.2.60
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.13

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Anyone an idea how to solve it? I have tried different package versions. I have deleted some cache folders like described in other stack overflow links. But no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

It worked with this command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

open build.gradle in android/app and set minSdkVersion 21
like that :

```
defaultConfig {       
    minSdkVersion 21
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

It worked for me after updating all the dependencies by running 'flutter pub cache repair' only this in terminal